# Remove unnecessary language options from menu bar

Tags: libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-writer

I am using page translate extension and it is working as expected.

https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/pagetranslate

The problem is I need to use Tools - Page Translate - Asia - Hindi everytime as shown in this image.

[image]

Can I keep only one option (english to hindi using google engine) and remove everything else? I do not think I will ever need it!

I checked the source code but I am not sure how to remove unnecessary code.
simplify it.

Comment: You have the last two buttons on the toolbar, at the top right. Do you never use them? Judging by the description, the second button (with the image of a flag) should translate the text to the local/system language. In other words, if your local language is Hindi, then there is no need to select the desired translation option from the menu-submenu-submenu - just click the button on the toolbar

Comment: The icon on the toolbar will translate the text from any other language to English. I just want it to always translate to Hindi. Is that possible? I tried to modify en to hi in Addons.xcu file 
<value>service:org.openoffice.comp.pyuno.pagetranslate?trigger&amp;lang=hi</value>

Comment: Most of the time, I work in English, but I also use Hindi from time to time. My default language is always English, though.

Comment: And by the way the keyboard shortcut (Accelerators.xcu) does not seem to work. Is it possible to assign a shortcut using GUI?

Comment: *I tried to modify en to hi in Addons.xcu file* - yes, this is the right way. I hope you made this change to the Addons.xcu file directly in the .oxt archive and then re-installed the extension from the corrected file? Or did you do it in another file?

Comment: Yes. I did exactly that. And still it does not translate to Hindi using the button. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that if I go to Tools - PageTranslate - Options and choose "select" in Button drop down, then it will ask "from" > "to" language codes next time when the button is pressed. I will like to remove all this complexity and keep only simple english to hindi one click (or one keyboard shortcut) translation.

Comment: Comments on the question are not the best place for discussion - I suggest moving to the [**chat**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253020/remove-unnecessary-language-options-from-menu-bar)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253021/discussion-between-shantanuo-and-johnsun).